# How to speed up basic pyspark statements

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark

As a new spark/pyspark user, I have a script running on an AWS t2.small ec2 instance in local mode (for testing purposes ony).

ie. As an example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark.ml.classification import NaiveBayesModel
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import ritc (my library)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("NaiveBayesExample")\
        .getOrCreate()
    ...
    request_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(ritc.request_parameters, ["features"])
    model = NaiveBayesModel.load(ritc.model_path)
    ...
    prediction = model.transform(ritc.request_dataframe)
    prediction.createOrReplaceTempView("result")
    df = spark.sql("SELECT prediction FROM result")
    p = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect())
    ...
```

I have left out code so as to focus on my question, relating to the speed of basic spark statements such as spark = SparkSession...

Using the datetime library (not shown above), I have timings for the three biggest 'culprits':

```
'spark = SparkSession...' -- 3.7 secs
'spark.createDataFrame()' -- 2.6 secs
'NaiveBayesModel.load()'  -- 3.4 secs
```

Why are these times so long??

To give a little background, I would like to provide the capability to expose scripts such as the above as REST services.

```
In supervised context:
- service #1: train a model and save the model in the filesystem
- service #2: load the model from the filesystem and get a prediction for a single instance
```

(Note: The #2 REST requests would run at different, and unanticipated (random) times. The general pattern would be:
    -> once: train the model - expecting a long turnaround time
    -> multiple times: request a prediction for a single instance - expecting a turnaround time in milliseconds - eg. < 400 ms.

Is there a flaw in my thinking? Can I expect to increase performance dramatically to achieve this goal of sub-second turnaround time?

In most every article/video/discussion on spark performance that I have come across, the emphasis has been on 'heavy' tasks. The 'train model' task above may indeed be a 'heavy' one - I expect this will be the case when run in production. But the 'request a prediction for a single instance' needs to be responsive.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in anticipation.

Colin Goldberg

Answer (score 0):

So ApacheSpark is designed to be used in this way. You might want to look at Spark Streaming if your goal is to handle streaming input data for predictions. You may also want to look at other options for serving Spark models, like PMML or MLeap.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. At this time, I am not sure that streaming data applies -- although this may turn out to be a factor. I will need to get up to speed (pun intended) re PMML and MLeap.